# Data Weave Pojo to Pojo Mappings

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

I am trying to do a Pojo to Pojo transformation as below( each Pojo has a List of objects) - the output is transformed but is skipping an object - sample code below.

```
public class Pojo1 implements Serializable {

 private List<Foo> fooList =new ArrayList<Foo>(1);

 public Pojo1() {
 }

 public List<Foo> getFooList() {
     return fooList ;
 }

 public void setFooList(List<Foo> fooList) {
     this.fooList= fooList;
 }
```

}

public class Pojo2 implements Serializable {

```
    private List<Bar> barList =new ArrayList<Bar>(1);

    public Pojo2() {
    }

    public List<Bar> getBarList() {
        return barList ;
    }

    public void setBarList(List<Bar> barList) {
        this.barList= barList;
    }

}
```

DataWeave transformation as follows - this works fine but only one object in the List gets transformed and I'm missing the second one.

```
   barList: [{
   ( 
       payload.fooList map {
           item1:$.item1                
       }
   )
   } as :object {
        class :"com.fooClass"
   }]
   } as :object {
       class : "com.barClass"
   }
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
{
  barList: in1.fooList map {
    item1: $.item1
  } as :object {class : "com.fooClass"}
} as :object {class : "com.barClass"}
```

Note: `as :object {class : "com.fooClass"}` should be optional, as it can be inferred

---

The problem seems to be that you defined an `array` with only `one object` and filled that object with the result of:

```
payload.fooList map {
  item1:$.item1                
}
```

Which is an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    item1: "value1"
  },
  {
    item1: "value2"
  }
]
```

After filling the object with that, it ends up like:

```
{
  item1: "value1",
  item1: "value2",
  item1: ...
}
```

So, you are filling the array with an object with a lot of duplicated fields (with different values) and when that output is written (since it's java) each one of those fields only get one value.